# Jquery checked input box based on url params

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show checked checkbox after loading based on the query string parameters, e.g.

`?brand=nike` the checkbox of nike should be checked by matching input value, however I can't see any checkbox is checked. Here is my code, thanks.

HTML

```
<form method="GET">
 <label class="form-check mb-2">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="nike">
  <span class="form-check-label"> Nike </span>
</label>
<label class="form-check mb-2">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="brand" value="adidas">
  <span class="form-check-label"> Adidas </span>
</label>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = new URL(window.location);
  var params = current_url.searchParams;
  var get_brandParams = params.getAll("brand");
  
  $.each(get_brandParams, function(key, value){
    var brand_value = value;
    $( "input[value=brand_value]" ).prop("checked", true); 
})
})
```

Comment: Is `current_url.searchParams;` supposed to be `url.searchParams;` ?

Comment: Also,  `$( "input[value=" + brand_value + "]" ).prop("checked", true);`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, you are right, thank you so much to fix my problem.